# How do American universities handle cases of discrimination?

Tags: united-states, university, legal-issues, discrimination

Many non-American students come to America in the hope of good education and support from their academic advisors.

How should anyone handle discrimination based on national origin by American professors if such a situation arises in the future?

How do universities take care of these situations, and do they treat non-American students and the American professors equally under the law?

Comment: What kind of discrimination? Is this an actual situation you are facing (in which case, please add some more details), or are you asking what resources / avenues are available if such a situation were to arise?

Comment: @GoodDeeds, have a look now.

Comment: How should one answer the last question? I am guessing each country with more than 100 people has one person treating people from different nations equally and one person treating them the same.

Comment: "Many American students stay in America in the hope of a good education and support from their academic advisors." Looking at various questions here, this doesn't always happen (although, of course, questions here are not a good statistical sample). A bad graduate experience may not stem from discrimination, and discrimination as defined in law differs from discrimination as perceived by people.

Comment: https://www2.ed.gov/about/offices/list/ocr/index.html

Comment: _do they treat non-American students and the American professors equally under the law?_ That depends what you mean. A professor and a student will have different rights defined by their respective contracts.

Comment: Some discrimination based on national origin is completely legal, such as funding sources that are only available to domestic students, or projects restricted for national security reasons. Anti-discrimination laws and policies do apply to categories that are correlated with national origins, though, such as race and religion. It's not clear what form of discrimination you are talking about.

Comment: I actually voted to close because I can't understand what the OP is asking, not because of _strongly depending on individual factors_.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Academia.SE! Unfortunately, this kind of question is off-topic here, on account of power users preferring that such issues be ignored. Your question has been closed, but good luck on the next one!

Comment: It's surprising that this has been closed. There are many similar questions that are open and highly voted. And the single answer this received seems good and suitable for this site.

Comment: I am also surprised! Now I feel like I am being gagged! @ knzhou @GoodDeeds, if anyone of you are admins, I request you to vote for reopening this question.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I am not. You could edit your question and try to address the comments here asking for clarification, and make it more concrete. The question will automatically be placed in the reopen queue for review. Other than that, if you still have concerns, you could ask a question on [Meta](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire: American universities are at the forefront of the fight to preserve good values and progressivism. Other nationalities should learn from it.

Comment: @knzhou The question is off-topic here because it is not a "practical, answerable [question] based on actual problems that [OP] face[s]." [ask] specifically instructs not to ask "an open-ended, hypothetical question: 'What if ______ happened?'" Also, it's off-topic because it's not answerable. American universities are not a monolith and will handle cases differently, depending on university and depending on specifics of a case.

Comment: An answerable, on-topic question would look like this: "I experienced [details of discriminatory action] at my university, whose anti-discrimination policy states [summarize the policy]. What should my next action be?"

Comment: @shoover Exactly such an "on-topic", specific question was locked and closed just today, out of fear that the details in it could harm the people doing the discrimination.

Comment: @knzhou Hope you have seen [this meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4793/68109), if that's the question you are referring to.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Indeed. The argument there is that specific allegations of discrimination are not useful to discuss. It's amusingly the exact opposite of the argument given to close this question -- that a general question about discrimination is not useful to discuss either. By putting the two together, you get a clear picture of what power users here believe it's useful to discuss: only what they personally want to hear.

Comment: To me, this question seems too broad: there are three different questions, the first two of which will vary widely for different situations and institutions. I agree that this could be reopened if it is made more concrete (i.e., so that it could be "answered" rather than "discussed"). Indeed, if you look at the "abuse" tag (for example), you will see many dozens of concrete situations this community has considered over the years. It is true that one specific, concrete situation was closed this week, but that was an unusual situation resolved transparently by a (very lopsided) democratic vote.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about classes, you can appeal in the usual ways.

It doesn't sound like you're talking about classes though, which makes it tough. If it's a bias / microaggression type situation your best bet is avoidance - find a new advisor. Quietly tell people who could be in the same situation (especially if you have an international student organization) that the professor is a problem. Be polite and professional and if anyone you don't completely trust asks about it, explain it was a personality conflict.

If it's a more serious issue, you should document it to the best of your ability and then bring it to a tenured professor in the department that you trust and ask for advice. However, in the absence of corroborating complaints from other students the likelihood of any real action being taken is minimal.

Escalating to HR is not advisable - HR minimizes legal risk to the university, but the minimum legal risk is usually telling you to take a semester leave of absence and then refusing to sign your I20.

The international student & visa situation in the US is very prone to abuse and you have very, very little leverage to fight back. It isn't impossible, but it isn't easy and even if successful you're likely to help future students but end up hurting yourself.